# Select same row multiple times

Tags: sql, jasper-reports, db2, ireport

I have a query that produces one row. I would like to output this one row multiple times, determined by a constant in this query. The query is on the format:

```
select A.a, B.b, C.c from A
inner join B ..
inner join C ..
where A.a =.. and B.b = .. and C.c = ..
```

This gives the result:

```
[A.a, B.b, C.c]
```

but what I want is, given that the constant is 3:

```
[A.a, B.b, C.c]
[A.a, B.b, C.c]
[A.a, B.b, C.c]
```

Is there an easy way to do this? Using UNION ALL with the query repeated doesn't work because I need to use a numeric value to specify the number of times the value should be repeated. This value will be a parameter for a report made with *iReport* with this query. If it could be done in *iReport* that would also work, but it has to be possible in a very old version of *iReport (3.0.0)*. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been googling this for hours but can't find a solution that works. It seems like it should be a simple task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need this? One way I am thinking of is to have number table with 100 rows (numbers from 1 to 100) and cross join with the original query

```
select t1.* from
(
select A.a, B.b, C.c from A
inner join B ..
inner join C ..
where A.a =.. and B.b = .. and C.c = ..
) as t1 inner join number_table on 1=1
where number<=3
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a report that print N barcode labels for a given article.
This solution works well, yhanks. But I'll hold on accepting this answer for a while because I'm hoping there is one that doesn't require creating a new table.

Comment: Having a physical table v.s. a generated table in memory has a few downsides.  Primarily that you will end up with a database object that has no business value, and is permanently part of your maintenance routines.  I don't see any compelling reasons to use a physical table rather than using a generated table like a recursive CTE to generate a number of rows.

Comment: @Madhivanan `1` is already a truely statement, no need to write the equation `1=1`. Even shorter yet: if these are your only 2 sources, just use the `t1, number_table` syntax to get the cartesian product instead of writing the defacto cross join

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursive SQL to generate a "table" with as many rows as you want, then join it with your original query, something like that:

```
with somerows(i) as (
  select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1
  union all
  select i+1 from somerows
  where i < ? -- this host variable would specify the number of rows
)
select A.a, B.b, C.c from 
somerows, 
A
inner join B ..
inner join C ..
where A.a =.. and B.b = .. and C.c = ..
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to a table to use in a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian%5fproduct).  Using a Cartesian product will multiply your business data results by the number of rows in the table.

I would generate the table as an in-memory table rather than a physical table.  That way you don't have additional database objects to maintain. The only reason I would create the number table as a physical table is as a performance optimization so that you don't incur the cost of building the table in-memory all the time. But I'm not even sure that would help, so I'd have to take some measurements to evaluate.

You could create that in-memory table in several ways:

1. Recursive SQL.
2. Declared Global Temporary Table, insert ? numbers into it.
3. Union a bunch of one row queries together.

Of those options, recursive SQL would be the best option, since you could get the result you want with a single SQL statement, and it sounds like you want to use an application that may not have the flexibility to build some of these more complex processes. The other two would either require dynamically building a SQL statement (for a union all) or inserting using the program a number of times.

For a recursive SQL in DB2, you would create a basic [Recursive CTE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.apsg/src/tpc/db2z%5fxmprecursivecte.htm) to generate the desired number of rows.

Keep the recursive portion separate from your actual business query so that the code is as clear as possible. When you come back to this in six months and it's not fresh in your mind, you want to be able to see a clear delineation between the generated values, and your business data SQL.

Add the recursive CTE at the top, and put a reference to it in the FROM clause of your original query.  That's all you should need:

```
with genrows(num) as (
  select 1 from sysibm.sysdummy1
    union all
  select num+1 from genrows
  where num < ? 
)

select A.a, B.b, C.c 
from genrows  /* and add genrows here to make the Cartesian product */
, A
inner join B ..
inner join C ..
where A.a =.. and B.b = .. and C.c = ..
```

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer the recursive CTE option myself (and would probably ignore the other options entirely) - could you give an example he could use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little workaround, but you can make a table, that contains number from 1 to 10 for example. Then you can join your row with this table where number_in_aux_table <= your constant.